# Using single bit mode with SD card and arduino

Tags: arduino, sd-card

I am trying to communicate with an SD card using an arduino, I got everything working using SPI but I found out that latest eMMC cards dont suport SPI more anymore and I need to communicate with an MMC somehow. My only problem is that I dont know how 1bit mode works, I searched everywhere on the internet and from what I understood it uses only a DO line which is data in for the host and a DI line which is data input for the host. I cant find any good documentation or an example of how to do this 1bit mode instead of using the old and good SPI mode. What my current code is doing is to initialize the SD card in spi mode, wait for the user to press a button to lock the card and another button to unlock it (using CMD42). Is there any good example for arduino how to use 1bit, or anyone could help me with a simple code which can initialize, send bytes to the card and then receive them.

Comment: eMMC is just MMC on a BGA. There should be NO operational difference.

Comment: I might suspect your problems may be with using resistor divider as the level shifter. This has been documented as a cause of inconsistency between devices. I have had great success with SdFatLib for Arduino. Note it can be configured for soft SPI. if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: But according to the MMC 4.4.1 standard there is no SPI anymore. I want to communicate with an integrated NAND chip from an 3DS (samsung KLM2G1DEHE-B101) and I dont think that this one supports SPI mode, thats why I want to know how to rewrite my code for it (also change the circuit to work with bidirectional lines)

Comment: can you provide a link to the reference.

Comment: http://yourcmc.ru/wiki/images/5/55/EMMC_JESD84-A441.pdf

Comment: It does appear this way. You may want to review individual manufacturer data sheets. As they may leave it in.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry that I can't answer your exact question, but I can offer hopefully valuable information that might help arduino developers to come up with a proper answer. Shortly, the eMMC does support a 1-bit communication mode but it is not SPI. It's a 3-pin MMC bus with clock and two bi-directional data lines.

Physically the arduino pins should be able to transfer information in the MMC bus mode, but some bit-banging is needed to handle the response from the MMC. I would say that the SPI hardware can't handle the CMD/RESP phase, so for that phase the bus should be bit-banged as GPIO. After that, the rest of the block data transfer probably could be handled by the SPI hardware.

In more depth, the MMC card (MultiMediaCard) is the common ancestor for both the MMC and the SD branches of memory cards. The SD branch is roughly something like MMC->sD->sDHC->sDXC. The MMC branch is roughly something like MMC->MMCplus->eMMC. They all are backwards compatible to MMC.

The old MMC v3 spec defined a 3-pin bus, which had a CLK pin and two bi-directional pins CMD and DAT. The CMD pin sends command from host to card **and** also a RESPonse from card to host. The DAT pin handles data transfer to and from the card, starting in parallel with the RESP.

To make MMC more compatible with microcontrollers, MMC defined an *optional* alternative transfer mode: SPI, with 4 pins CS, CLK, CMD and DAT, where CMD and DAT are unidirectional and the RESPonse comes in the DAT pin instead of the CMD pin. Later, the SD specification flagged the SPI mode as mandatory, but the MMC specification did not. As a result, some of the current MMC cards and eMMC chips have the SPI capability and some of them don't have. But all should be able to fall back to the old MMC type bus which had one clock and two bi-directional lines CMD and DAT.

Technically, it would be great if the eMMC would have descended from SD so that the SPI mode would be mandatory. But then we'd need to pay royalties to the SD card association. MMC charges no such fees, afaik.

Answer (score 1):

it still is SPI transfer, it's just the way it is operated that is a bit special. Look on wikipedia for the matter.

Though, you've got an Arduino library implementing SD/MMC transfers:

```
http://playground.arduino.cc/Learning/SDMMC
```

Ok looking further on the topic, there are indeed differences between SD and MMC protocols:

- http://www.datasheetarchive.com/dl/Datasheets-EC1/DSAQ00203957.pdf

  - describes the eMMC 4.41 specification, and what looks like a parallel mode for data transfers
- https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/pls/simplified_specs/archive/part1_301.pdf

  - describe the SD Bus protocol as well as the more common SPI one
  - some guys have begun [an implementation of the SD Bus protocol for rasp pi](http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=72&t=59395).

But when you say *"it uses only a DO line which is data in for the host and a DI line which is data input for the host."* (though I did not find documentation to confirm the naming), it's still describing a SPI like protocol. SPI is only about having host->device, device->host, clock, chip select lines. And then there are hundreds of ways you can configure data to be sent through it. So even though it's not necessarily called "SPI" I'm pretty sure you can still configure your arduino to use the hardware SPI to send/receive commands in that close-to-SPI mode.

But if you look closely at the eMMC 4.41, it's a totally different scheme, as it is a BGA memory card, it has a lot more contacts, and as far as I've read the spec, it looks to me to use some kind of parallel transfer, not serial.

Comment: That library uses SPI, I been using that before, now I am using a library made by Roland http://www.roland-riegel.de/sd-reader/ which fits my needs much better.So for the one bit mode I dont have to rewrite the entire library only some parts of it ?

Comment: Roland's library is using SPI, also.

Comment: Roland's library works perfectly with SD card and some type of MMC card, it also works with the eMMC chip from 3DS (Samsung one, toshiba ones never initialize)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, some portable DVD players will work fine in JPG/BMP/PNG mode and only some pins are connected. I think this is done on purpose so that they can be used as digital picture frames thus avoiding the SD Card Association fees.
Unfortunately this also means they can't play video from the card, nor be used with more modern SD or microSD cards having higher capacity because these typically lack single bit mode.
I found that at least with mine it will work with a 32GB SD but not anything larger, 4GB is known to work on every player tested including MP3 headphones.
Incidentally if you are really stuck some FakeFlash (tm) cards will work fine if you write a disk image file of less than the real capacity just for playback eg 2GB.
Just be sure not to use it for important data and ideally cover the incorrect markings so there is no confusion.